# Breakout board for EFM8BB1

Tags: microcontroller, schematics

I am making a breakout board for Silabs EFM8BB1 (Busybee). I have made the schematic but am unsure about the C2 Debug Interface. Can someone guide me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be following the configuration in the application note https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN124.pdf 
[image] 
that allows you to share the C2 debug pins with RESET and GPIO.

That app note is missing the debugger part of the connection, if you see the pinout in the Debug adapter and the eval boards. https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2017/03/22/using_the_usb_debug-XeTq
[image]

**(Note that I didnt put the red Highlights as those are the simple connection without pin share)**

Pins 5 and 6 of the table are the **pin share** connections, so they arent actually the same pins as your schematic shows.

**Following your original schematic:**

- The node after R1 (the second D_C2CKC label) should go to a header for **pin5 C2CKC_share**
- The node after R2   (the second D_C2D label)should go to a header for **pin6 C2D_share**

So adding the pins to your **J3** header:

- 1 Empty
- 2 D-GND
- 3 D-C2D
- 4 D-C2CK
- 5 D-C2CK_**SHARE**
- 6 D-C2D_**SHARE**

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying pin sharing is not relevant for my schematic since i'm just using the basic C2 debug?

Comment: I am unable to post the updated schematic as picture in comments. https://ibb.co/e17iRw Please have a look.

Comment: @Werty37 
IF you  want to be able to use those pins as RESET and GPIO P2.0  at the SAME time as using the debugger you need the full pin share connection as I was suggesting. 
But IF you can live without using those pins at the same time you could use the new schematic. I hope it makes it clear. (Note that I didnt put the red Highlights as those are the simple connection without pin share)

Comment: I understood that I need bidirectional C2 interfacing after looking at AN124. What i am still unsure about is J3. Does both the D-C2CK connects to Pin4 in J3 and both the D-C2D connects to Pin3 in J3? https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/forum.topic.html/breakout_board_fore-OaE7

Comment: They dont connect to the same pin. Please review my edited answer. @Werty37

Comment: So I will need a minimum of 5 header pins to use bidirectional C2 interfacing. From the usb debug adapter connector; Pins 4, 5, 6, 7 and one of the ground (Pin 2/3/9). The connections would go the way you have mentioned in the edited answer. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it. If my answer helped you please mark it as answer and upvote it. @Werty37

Comment: Can you please include the updated schematic in your answer if it is fine? https://imgur.com/a/ZSgRg